# How to make an API call without exposing the key (HTTPS)

Tags: api

I was working on a project, and needed to make an API call to my website `https://dashboard.lawliet.host/api/setcoins`, it took in a header `Authorization`, which was the admin API key.

I obviously don't want the API key exposed to the user if they check the outgoing requests, or deobfuscate the program. What is a good and easy solution to get around this?

What I did think of what to hash the API key in this program, and compare it with the key in my server. According to me, this will work, but I do want to know if there's a better/easier way to accomplish it.

P.S: English is not my first language, so if anyone could edit this question and fix any grammatical errors, I would appreciate it.

Thanks,
MisuteriasuKe

Comment: If you don't want a user to know a key then the **ONLY** option is to not give it to him in the first place. Keep the key in the servers, or provide some keys you don't bother exposing. What's your concern with exposing such key in the first place? Is it a key to an outside service?

Comment: It is usually better not to give them real API keys, give them a temporary token tied to the current session and make calls to a proxy on the server using that token instead of API keys you want to keep secret.  Client => token => proxy URL on server => server makes API call.  Or just use the session itself as authorization for the proxy URL.